# How to fill Database in Session?

Tags: java, database, session

I am developing a java project where I do have to fill database from http://projects.zoho.com.

Zoho provides API for fatching data. I have developed java transformers for fatching data and using hibernate I feel database.

This process, I do, running Main method from transformer. I want there a session to help filling database automatically. What further step I should follow ?

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you elaborate a litte more? What have you done until now?  Your problem is that you don't know how to use hibernate? or how to open a session in hibernate? Or how to persist the data?

Comment: First time when I deploy my application, it will fill the database itself. Then at regular interval of time, I want the database gets refreshed itself. So that I have to use a session, in which database remains intact & at end of session it will automatically gets filled itself. But, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with a good design of your database and then use database normalization techniques.
Then use JConnector for your database.
If you care about the physical order of data fetched in the disk use some technique to sort the data in main memory before you store it in disk.
If the data in disk is not still as sorted as you want use external hashing technique.

The session will be triggered when the limit of fetched data in main memory is up to the limit you specify.